# Visual Basic FTP File Zilla Server?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class sendftp

Public Function UploadFileToFtp(ByVal f As String, ByVal host As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal folderToUploadTo As String) As Boolean
    Try
        'create an FtpRequest object, holds the value of the path you are trying to reach
        Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(host & "/" & Path.GetFileName(folderToUploadTo))), FtpWebRequest)

        'pass in our login credentials
        ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)

        'set the method to Upload, since we're uploading a file
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile


        'don't use passive mode
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = True
        'unless we're uploading a file like an image
        'we need to set this to false as we're not uploading
        'binary data
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = True
        'set KeepAlive to false
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = False

        'now create a new FileStream, then open the file we're uploading
        'this allows us to get the size of the file for our buffer
        Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(f)
        'create a byte[] array buffer the size of the file
        'we're uploading
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(stream.Length - 1) {}

        'read in our file into the FileStream
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        'close the FileStream
        stream.Close()

        'create a new stream, this will be used to write to the
        'FTP server
        Dim requestStream As Stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream()
        'write the data to the FTP server
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        'close the stream
        requestStream.Close()
        'since we made it this far return true
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        'something went wront so let the user know
        MessageBox.Show("Error uploading file: " + ex.Message, "Upload Error")
        'return false
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    UploadFileToFtp("C:\file.txt", "ftp://ftp.drivehq.com", "**user**", "**password**", "new.txt")



End Sub
End Class
```

And it works.

However I would like to use my FileZilla Server, so I edit the ftp url:

```
UploadFileToFtp("C:\file.txt", "ftp://localhost", "**user**", "**password**", "new.txt")
```

but I get this error:

> The remote server returned an error:(550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be permission that I fixed by going to ftp server settings.